# SAS creating subtables ordered by year

Tags: sas

I have a table in SAS which consists of data from stock exchange. One of its columns holds information about date. I would like to create subtables, each one hold data from only one specific year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this (often, this is an inferior option as analyses run separately by year can be run from one dataset using `by year;`, but certainly this can sometimes be appropriate), the gold standard method for doing this is the hash table, as the hash table can produce unlimited tables based on the data.  I will edit in a method for doing this with hash table if I have time while running things this afternoon; it's the 'hashing' method described on [this page](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Split_Data_into_Subsets).

Hashing code, adapted from the sascommunity.org page above:

```
data have;
call streaminit(7);
do year=1998 to 2014;
  do id=  1 to 10;
    x=rand('Uniform');
    output;
  end;
end;
run;


data _null_ ;
  dcl hash byyear   () ;
  byyear.definekey  ('k') ; if `id` or similar is a safe unique ID you could use that here, otherwise `k` is your unique identifier - hash requires unique;
  byyear.definedata ('year','id','x') ;
  byyear.definedone () ;
  do k = 1 by 1 until ( last.year ) ;
    set have;
    by year ;
    byyear.add () ;
  end ;
  dsetname=cats('year',year);
  byyear.output (dataset: dsetname) ;
run ;
```

There is a similar set of methods that revolve around using a macro to generate the code.  [This paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/069-2012.pdf) goes into detail about one method to do that; I won't explain it in detail as I consider it inferior to the hash method (even if it is lower CPU time, it is more complicated to write than either a pure macro method or a pure hash method) but in certain cases it could be better.

A simple example of the macro method using the conceptual `have` aframe defined:

```
proc sql;
  select distinct(cats('year',year(date))) into :dsetlist 
   separated by ' '
   from have;
  select distinct(cats('%outputyear(year=',year(date),')')) into :outputlist
   separated by ' '
   from have;
quit;

%macro outpuyear(year=);
  if year(date)=&year. then output year&dset.;
%mend outputyear;

data &dsetlist.;
  set have;
   &outputlist.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data year1 year2 year3 yearN;
    set stockdata;
    if year(date) = 2014 then
        output year1;
    else if year(date) = 2013 then
        output year2;
    else if year(date) = 2012 then
        output year3;
    else 
        output yearN;
run;
```

You could also use case statements I guess.